# Bitcoin synchronization freezes my computer

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, bitcoin, fedora-16

I've a fairly decent laptop, with good CPU, 4Go of ram and a SSD harddrive. Nevertheless, when I run the bitcoin client (0.4 or 0.5), the whole computer freezes for several minutes then is usable for a few minutes then freezes again, etc.

I've monitored: CPU is low (bitcoin uses 10%), memory is low (bitcoin uses 3%), network isnormal (bitcoin uses 50/100Kb/s).

I'm wondering: am I alone experiencing this? Is there any way to be able to use a computer while, at the same time, having the bitcoin client running?

Thanks

PS: I'm currently using Fedora 16 but I had the same problem with Ubuntu 11.10 and 11.04.

Comment: check if its using your gpu

Comment: What tool do you use to check that?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin synchronization is a process that [relies heavily on disk IOs](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/13hstk/downloading_the_bitcoin_08_client_that_uses/). In the upcoming Bitcoin-QT version 0.8, the file system will be changed to use LevelDB that is less hard-drive intensive. It may be the case that this will solve your problem.

At any rate, the synchronisation is a long process, so it is best to do the initial process while not working on the computer, for example over multiple nights. After that the process of catching up should be faster and require less time and resources (that is unless a lot of people start playing [SatoshiDice](http://satoshidice.com/) and bloat the blockchain).

Alternatively, try using an [eWallet](https://blockchain.info/wallet/) to avoid synchronisation problems altogether. Though this option sacrifices a bit of security for a lot of convenience. Best used with just a few bitcoins in case something bad happens.